# std::getline is reading line where specified delimiter is not present?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I want to print each object in console from the array of the following string (stored in a file):

```
{ beforechars [{Object1},{Object2},{Object3}] afterchars }
```

I'm doing it as follows:

```
std::ifstream is("content.txt");
std::getline(is, content, '[');
while (std::getline(is,content,'{')) {
    std::getline(is,content,'}');
    std::cout << content << std::endl;
}
in.close();
```

But i am getting this output:

```
 Object1
 Object2
 Object3
] afterchars }
```

My understanding is that after `Object3` iteration, the `ifstream` should have "*}] afterchars }*" and the while's guard shouldn't be true because there isn't any '*{*' char... Am i right? Where is the mistake?

Comment: `std::getline` also extracts the delimiter, that's why there's no `}`.

Comment: @LogicStuff Yeah, i get that. what i didn't understand was why the console was printing last line if there was any '{' chars left, but as Cristophe said, `getline` apparently prints the entire file if it doesn't find the delimiter... Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The while condition doesn't work as you expect:  [`getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) will read successfully until it reaches an '{' or to the end of the file if not.

So what happens here ?

- when you've displayed `Object3` your position in the stream is after the closing `'}'`.
- The `getline()` in the `while` condition will read all the remaining of the file into `content` as it encounters no `'{'`.  As it could read something successfully, the condition is evaluated to true.
- the `getline()` within the `while` block then fails to read anything, so `content` will remain unchanged. The stream is then in fail status.  No subsequent operation will succeed until you clear this state.  But nothing visible happens for now in your code.
- after displaying this last result, the next loop condition will fail.

**Simple workaround:**

A very easy workaround would be to keep the current position in the stream before looking for `'{'`, and in case it was not found, go back to this position.  Attention:  this way of parsing files is not so nice from point of view of performance, but it's ok for small files.

```
std::getline(is, content, '[');
auto pos = is.tellg();    // read current position
while (std::getline(is,content,'{') && !is.eof()) { 
    std::getline(is,content,'}');
    pos = is.tellg();     // update position before iterating again
    std::cout << content << std::endl;
}
is.seekg(pos);   // and get back to last position
```

The trick here is that if `'{'` is not found, after the `getline()` the stream is not yet in fail state, but `eof()` is already true.  We can then end the loop and go back to the last recorded position.

**[Online demo](http://ideone.com/wxfDOd)**

Comment: Ohh i get it... is there a way to tell getline to not keep reading if it doesn't find the specified delimiter? Or do you have any idea about how could i fix this? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`std::getline` reads characters until delimiter (consuming it) *or until the end of the stream*. It sets failbit on stream only if there were no character consumed (called on empty/invalid stream).

So your loop will terminate only when stream is empty.

Streams interface allows only to see next character, there is no way to scan input and do read if there specific character present.

If you need random access to characters, you need to read input in string and then parse it (with regular expressions or something else.)